# Edit Json file With Python?

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, ipython, jupyter-notebook

I am new in python. also never work with JSON. I have json file which I can't open because of missing "," in line 8. so how to fix this with python.and i went know how to handle missing values in JSON file with python json lib.

i use python3 with ipython

python script which i use:

```
import json

with open('name_dob_height.json') as json_file:
d = json.load(json_file)
print(d)
```

and error massage last line:

```
JSONDecodeError: Expecting ',' delimiter: line 8 column 3 (char 109)
```

json_file =

```
[
{
    "First_name": "Nathan",
    "Last_name": "Astle",
    "Date_of_birth": "1971-05-18",
    "Height": "155"

}{
    "First_name": "Nathan",
    "Last_name": "Astle",
    "Date_of_birth": "1971-05-19",
    "Height": "155"

},
{
    "First_name": "Arthur",
    "Last_name": "Harrison",
    "Date_of_birth": "1982-01-29",
    "Height": "168"

},
{
    "First_name": "Cameron",
    "Last_name": "White",
    "Date_of_birth": "1982-01-29",
    "Height": "170"

},
{
    "First_name": "Steve",
    "Last_name": "Finn",
    "Date_of_birth": "1971-05-18",
    "Height": "189"

},
{
    "First_name": "Elliot",
    "Last_name": "Luca",
    "Date_of_birth": "1971-05-18",
    "Height": "172"

},
{
    "First_name": "Methews",
    "Last_name": "Haiden",
    "Date_of_birth": "1971-05-18",
    "Height": "165"

},
{
    "First_name": "John",
    "Last_name": "Smith",
    "Date_of_birth": "1971-05-18",
    "Height": "invalid string"

},
{
    "First_name": "Daniel",
    "Last_name": "Clerk",
    "Date_of_birth": "1971-05-18",
    "Height": "190"

},
{
    "First_name": "Allan",
    "Last_name": "Hernandez",
    "Date_of_birth": "1981-01-19",
    "Height": "178"

},
{
    "First_name": "Harley",
    "Last_name": "Smith",
    "Date_of_birth": "1988-05-21",
    "Height": "185"

},
{
    "First_name": "Nathaniel",
    "Last_name": "Stewert",
    "Date_of_birth": "1980-08-10",
    "Height": "125"

},
{
    "First_name": "Michael",
    "Last_name": "Johnson",
    "Date_of_birth": "1990-03-26",
    "Height": "152"

}
```

]

Comment: for json file you have to use json module. Google it you will find.

Comment: @Narendra looks like OP is already using json module

Comment: After the first object, there is no comma in JSON file. Please add comma it would solve your problem.

Comment: @kvk30 i can manually do this. i went with python program

Comment: @NajeebChoudhary with proper format of Json, It is not possible.

Comment: @kvk30 it not possible or it is impossible

Comment: @NajeebChoudhary not getting you?

Comment: This question should be closed since it is a simple typographical error.

Answer (score 2):

Please update your JSON file, it would help you. Before checking any JSON file please verify in this link, [JSON validator](https://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/)

json_file =

```
    [
    {
        "First_name": "Nathan",
        "Last_name": "Astle",
        "Date_of_birth": "1971-05-18",
        "Height": "155"

    },
   {
        "First_name": "Nathan",
        "Last_name": "Astle",
        "Date_of_birth": "1971-05-19",
        "Height": "155"

    },
    {
        "First_name": "Arthur",
        "Last_name": "Harrison",
        "Date_of_birth": "1982-01-29",
        "Height": "168"

    },
    {
        "First_name": "Cameron",
        "Last_name": "White",
        "Date_of_birth": "1982-01-29",
        "Height": "170"

    },
    {
        "First_name": "Steve",
        "Last_name": "Finn",
        "Date_of_birth": "1971-05-18",
        "Height": "189"

    },
    {
        "First_name": "Elliot",
        "Last_name": "Luca",
        "Date_of_birth": "1971-05-18",
        "Height": "172"

    },
    {
        "First_name": "Methews",
        "Last_name": "Haiden",
        "Date_of_birth": "1971-05-18",
        "Height": "165"

    },
    {
        "First_name": "John",
        "Last_name": "Smith",
        "Date_of_birth": "1971-05-18",
        "Height": "invalid string"

    },
    {
        "First_name": "Daniel",
        "Last_name": "Clerk",
        "Date_of_birth": "1971-05-18",
        "Height": "190"

    },
    {
        "First_name": "Allan",
        "Last_name": "Hernandez",
        "Date_of_birth": "1981-01-19",
        "Height": "178"

    },
    {
        "First_name": "Harley",
        "Last_name": "Smith",
        "Date_of_birth": "1988-05-21",
        "Height": "185"

    },
    {
        "First_name": "Nathaniel",
        "Last_name": "Stewert",
        "Date_of_birth": "1980-08-10",
        "Height": "125"

    },
    {
        "First_name": "Michael",
        "Last_name": "Johnson",
        "Date_of_birth": "1990-03-26",
        "Height": "152"

    }
]
```

Answer (score 1):

I see in your code that there is a delimiter missing in your `JSON` file. You can add a delimiter at line 8. After doing this `json` file can open without any problem.
In code have no problem.

Answer (score 0):

**Use module JSON**

```
import json

with open('your_file.json') as json_data:
    d = json.load(json_data)
    print(d)
```

Comment: Problem is a missing comma. OP is already using json

Comment: your assumption is wrong, he is using JSON module. If he don't use it then it would throw another error.

Comment: he showd he is having json file and wants to read it through python script right?

Comment: Yeah, but the schema of JSON is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

You have a error in your JSON. Please use the corrected json:

```
[{"First_name":"Nathan","Last_name":"Astle","Date_of_birth":"1971-05-18","Height":"155"},{"First_name":"Nathan","Last_name":"Astle","Date_of_birth":"1971-05-19","Height":"155"},{"First_name":"Arthur","Last_name":"Harrison","Date_of_birth":"1982-01-29","Height":"168"},{"First_name":"Cameron","Last_name":"White","Date_of_birth":"1982-01-29","Height":"170"},{"First_name":"Steve","Last_name":"Finn","Date_of_birth":"1971-05-18","Height":"189"},{"First_name":"Elliot","Last_name":"Luca","Date_of_birth":"1971-05-18","Height":"172"},{"First_name":"Methews","Last_name":"Haiden","Date_of_birth":"1971-05-18","Height":"165"},{"First_name":"John","Last_name":"Smith","Date_of_birth":"1971-05-18","Height":"invalid string"},{"First_name":"Daniel","Last_name":"Clerk","Date_of_birth":"1971-05-18","Height":"190"},{"First_name":"Allan","Last_name":"Hernandez","Date_of_birth":"1981-01-19","Height":"178"},{"First_name":"Harley","Last_name":"Smith","Date_of_birth":"1988-05-21","Height":"185"},{"First_name":"Nathaniel","Last_name":"Stewert","Date_of_birth":"1980-08-10","Height":"125"},{"First_name":"Michael","Last_name":"Johnson","Date_of_birth":"1990-03-26","Height":"152"}]
```

i.e. you were missing a comma `,` after first object in JSON

Comment: yes file is missing comma in line no 8